# Symfony 4 - Form - "This Value is not valid" when passing Date from Angular

Tags: php, angular, date, symfony, datetime

I am attempting to hit an endpoint to update an `Auction` entity, which has a `start_date` and `end_date` property, both of type `DateTimeType`. However, when I pass an `Auction` entity to my API from my Angular front-end, I am being told that the `start_date` and `end_date` values are not valid.

Here is the current state of my `AuctionType` (Form):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('company', TextType::class)
            ->add('minimum_unit_price', NumberType::class)
            ->add('maximum_unit_amount', NumberType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add('num_units', NumberType::class)
            ->add('end_date', DateTimeType::class, [
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                ])
            ->add('start_date', DateTimeType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                ])
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            ->add('slug', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add(
                'editors',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => User::class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'choice_label' => 'email',
                    // This will need improvement later down the line - but fine for now
                    // TODO: This shouldn't include the own user
                    'choice_value' => function (?User $user) {
                        return $user ? $user->getEmail() : '';
                    },
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );
    }
```

Here is the model being passed from the front-end:

```
    const auctionUpdate: AuctionType = {
      company: this.auctionForm.controls.company.value,
      description: this.auctionForm.controls.description.value,
      editors: [],
      end_date: this.datePipe.transform(this.auction.end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
      maximum_unit_amount: this.auction.maximum_unit_amount,
      minimum_unit_price: this.auction.minimum_unit_price,
      name: this.auctionForm.controls.title.value,
      num_units: this.auction.num_units,
      slug: this.auction.slug,
      start_date: this.datePipe.transform(this.auction.start_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    };
```

Note: The `this.auction.start_date` and `this.auction.end_date` are of the type Date.I have tried two different date formats, such as `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (our desired format).

I am relatively new to Symfony and PHP in general, so this may be basic. What am I missing here??

My understanding is that passing a date in the form of a string is valid in Symfony according to their documentation on the `DateTimeType` and I am matching the date format of all other dates stored in our database. So, I am not too sure why this is being rejected.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

PS: If you need more context/code to look at in order to assess the issue, please let me know and I will add it!

Comment: You might want to check what it looks like ‘over the wire’ in your network console. Does that match what you need serverside?

Comment: @MikeOne it is identical! My `end_date` looks like this: `"2022-03-16 13:09:29"`. The `start_date` is: `2022-03-16 13:04:29`

Comment: Is the entity field in the php side an actual `DateTime` object? "matching the date format of all other dates stored in our database" makes it sound as it isn't, since that would be determined by the db engine. If that's the case, try changing the [`input`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#input) to `string`. More details about the exception would be helpful if you have access to the profiler.

Comment: @msg the startDate and endDate on the `Auction` entity are both `DateTime`. They are annotated as follows: `@ORM\Column(type="datetime")`. Could you elaborate a bit on what `input` you are referencing?

I'm not sure how to find more about the exception. The response is pretty broad and I haven't been able to successfully set up xDebug yet.

Comment: `input` is an option of the `DateTimeType` field, but if it's an actual datetime the default should be fine. About the profiler, it's a symfony package to aid development and doesn't need xdebug, more info on how to install in the [component page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html). You should get more info about the exception in the "Form" or "Validator" panes shown in the screenshot.